# How to engineer a "message read/message not read" fucntionality like the tchat apps or forums ones?

Tags: microservices, messaging, vue.js

I am challenged to rebuild a support ticket manager app currently on legacy PHP code.

I plan to migrate to microservices + JS frontend technology like VueJS or React.

One of the app's page is a support ticket page, with a comment section. There is currently a trigger that registers the visit date of a user on the page ticket in a "history" database table. It then compares the last visit date to the comment createdAt date to determine is the user read the new message or not. It's more like a kind of forum messages stack rather than a realtime tchat app.

Pros: its simple Cons: it doesn't look profesionnal to me as any front html loading triggers the "message read" despite if the user really read the message (ex: clicked the tchat tab to display messages, scrolled down to it, etc).

I was wondering how the modern apps would solve this issue. For example, I thought about using some kind of session info instead to compared with the messages creation date retrived from the api. Maybe the better way would be to have this functionality built in the component which displays the messages, so I can control if the retrived message object is displayed successfully, including the "user last visit date vs message creation date comparison".

Did you guys built this in the past using JS apps? With which pattern or solution did you implement that ?

Thanks for pointing me in the nicest direction <3

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386627/how-to-engineer-a-message-read-message-not-read-fucntionality-like-the-tchat-a "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: you will never have certainty since we can scroll up and down with a finger and go through countless messages in less than a second. You could, tho, mark the message as read based on the time the message has been displayed. But it will take you to know, more or less, how long takes to read each message.

Comment: @Laiv I will approximate then, no problem with that, but what I would like to know is if the "compare message creation to stored last user visit" is the best pattern... Is it always about comparing some date stored alongside the user session informations, or is there any better way to determine the read status (like maybe storing a copy of the messages on the clients side or whatever) ?

Comment: Nothing is done "always" the same way. Not even the same problem is "always" solved with the same solution. Not in Software engineering. It depends on many things and very few are technical. Most are driven by business or business expectations. If users reading (like really doing it) messages is so important then the solution is `A`, but if you don't care and only need to show a red badge, then the solution is `B`. If you need both, the solution is not `AB`, is C. And C is implemented in different ways on Twiter, Stack Exchange or Facebook.

Comment: I am aware that a solution is obviously not always implemented the same way, I am only asking about examples of the best or the usual patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not possible to really know whether a user actually read a message or skipped over it, you need to use an approximation which may be right most of the time but sometimes wrong. Which one to use and what level of inaccuracy is acceptable really depends on the application - when the content has legal implications you may require the user to tick a checkbox stating that they read the blurb, for other cases much simpler approaches are fine. If the mechanism in the old version was sufficient for your organization before, there's no convincing reason to invent something new now.

So my advice would be to just implement the old algorithm within your new application. To me it looks simple, straightforward, and most likely sufficient for the purpose, and if I had to implement such a functionality in a new application I would perhaps just do it like that.